# pop and push from one associative array to another array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I want to pop from array2 and want to push in array1.
But according to some custom requirement.

Now in array1 there is 1st key's readingOrder is 1 and 2nd key's readingOrder is 4.

So i want to push between this two key from array2's first two key.And same process for all other.

and my final array must be like array3.

**for example in array1 key[0] readingOrder is 1 and key[1]'s 4. Now i want to push another two key from array2.
for array1 key[2] reading order is 6. so before this key i want to push another one key from array2 and same for further...**

**array1 is like below**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [readingOrder] => 1
            [id] => 78
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [readingOrder] => 4
            [id] => 76
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [readingOrder] => 6
            [id] => 80
        )

)
```

**array2 is like below**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 81
            [readingOrder] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 82
            [readingOrder] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 84
            [readingOrder] => 7
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 85
            [readingOrder] => 8
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 86
            [readingOrder] => 9
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 87
            [readingOrder] => 10
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 88
            [readingOrder] => 11
        )

)
```

**Output array3:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [readingOrder] => 1
            [id] => 78
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 81
            [readingOrder] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 82
            [readingOrder] => 5
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [readingOrder] => 4
            [id] => 76
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 84
            [readingOrder] => 7
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [readingOrder] => 6
            [id] => 80
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 85
            [readingOrder] => 8
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 86
            [readingOrder] => 9
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [id] => 87
            [readingOrder] => 10
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [id] => 88
            [readingOrder] => 11
        )

)
```

**Thanks..**

Comment: What have your prior attempts to get the right output look like?  More specifically exactly what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @GordonM i edit my question. Please read now.

Comment: You didn't understand what @GordonM asked, the question is: for what reason do you need to do that? (and also *Could you show your attempt(s) to solve the problem?*)

Answer (score 1):

You can build your array like that:

```
$current = 1;
$arr3 = [];
while ( $arr1 && $arr2 ) {
    if ( $arr1[0]['readingOrder'] > $current )
        $arr3[] = array_shift($arr2);
    else
        $arr3[] = array_shift($arr1);
    $current++;
}

$arr3 = array_merge($arr3, $arr1, $arr2);

print_r($arr3);
```

Note that this code is destructive for `$arr1` and `$arr2`. If you want to preserve them, copy them before and use the copies instead.

Comment: Thank a lot. This ans is exact as per my requirment.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `usort`. First you need to merge the arrays:

```
$a1 = [
    [
        'readingOrder' => 1,
        'id' => 78
    ],
    [
        'readingOrder' => 4,
         'id' => 76
    ],
    [
        'readingOrder' => 6,
        'id' => 80
    ]
];
$a2 = [
    [
        'readingOrder' => 2,
        'id' => 81
    ],
    [
        'readingOrder' => 5,
        'id' => 82
    ],
    [
        'readingOrder' => 7,
        'id' => 84
    ],
    [
        'readingOrder' => 8,
        'id' => 85
    ]
];

$a3 = array_merge($a1, $a2);
```

Then you need to use `usort`:

```
usort($a3, function($a,$b) {
    if ($a['readingOrder'] == $b['readingOrder']) return 0;
    return $a['readingOrder'] < $b['readingOrder'] ? -1 : 1;
});
```

In PHP 7 you can now use the spaceship operator, which would make the code more clean. Like so:

```
usort($a3, function($a,$b) {
    return $a[0] <=> $b[0];
});
```

This will then return:

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [readingOrder] => 1
            [id] => 78
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [readingOrder] => 2
            [id] => 81
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [readingOrder] => 4
            [id] => 76
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [readingOrder] => 5
            [id] => 82
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [readingOrder] => 6
            [id] => 80
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [readingOrder] => 7
            [id] => 84
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [readingOrder] => 8
            [id] => 85
        )

)
```

Comment: It isn't what he asked.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte My bad then. I must say it's not very clear what he is trying to achieve either.

Comment: The desired result is clear but the reason why he wants to do that is a deep mystery.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Which in result makes things unclear for me haha

Comment: actully i want to keep array1 readingOrder as it is. and from array2 i want to push remaining places..

Comment: for example in array1 key[0] readingOrder is 1 and key[1]'s 4. Now i want to push another two key from array2.

for array1 key[2] reading order is 6. so before this key i want to push another one key from array2.